# Convert a collection into an Eloquent object

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent, method-chaining, xero-api

Currently I'm using the Xero API inside Laravel 5.2. I would like to use the power of Eloquent with this data.

Actually I can recover invoices and even filter them using chaining methods as shown:

```
    $invoices = XeroPrivate::load('Accounting\\Invoice')
        ->where('Status', 'DRAFT')
        ->execute();
```

If I do a `var_dump`, I get this kind of data:

```
object(XeroPHP\Remote\Collection)[173]
  public 0 => 
    object(XeroPHP\Models\Accounting\Invoice)[171]
      protected '_data' => 
        array (size=31)
          'Type' => string 'ACCPAY' (length=6)
          'Contact' =>
```

Eloquent chaining methods would let me to execute things like this. Currently it fails:

```
    $invoices = XeroPrivate::load('Accounting\\Invoice')
        ->where('Date','>','2016-03-20')
        ->execute();
```

Checking Laravel's docs, it is supposed I could convert into a collection with `collect`:

```
    $collection = collect($invoices);
```

`$collection` does not solve the problem. Now data structure is different but still can't use Eloquent. Now data is:

```
object(Illuminate\Support\Collection)[163]
  protected 'items' => 
    array (size=24)
      0 => 
        object(XeroPHP\Models\Accounting\Invoice)[171]
          protected '_data' => 
            array (size=31)
```

But it is shown data is `Illuminate\Support\Collection` and seems to be right.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can take a single item of the collection by using `first()` method.

```php
$entity = $collection->first();
```

[You can find more information here](https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/Support/Collection.html) about what methods you have available of `Illuminate\Support\Collection`.

Comment: Thanks! but still is not working... doing:    `$collection = collect($invoices);
        var_dump($collection->first()->where('Status','DRAFT'));`  throws an error: `Call to undefined method XeroPHP\Models\Accounting\Invoice::where()`

Comment: Why are you using `where()` on a Entity? The `Model` is not a query builder. You need to use `first()->query()->where()->get()` if you want to use the Model as a query builder.